# Using Selenium how to Assert zoomed image

Tags: image, selenium, zooming

Using selenium with java i want to very whether a image is zoomed when cursor is moved over the image .From the source code below element change

Before zoom
`<div class="powatag-zoom powatag-hidden">`

After zoom
`<div class="powatag-zoom">`

Any help to assert the change welcome

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution can be get the class attribute of your element:

```
webelement.getAttribute("class")
```

Then parse the result and assert that contains `powatag-hidden`

Hope that helps.

Comment: you didn't provide in which language you're working, so I wrote a generic way to solve your issue. I help you by giving you some pointers. You should try to solve the problem by yourself with that help, or ask for clarification if needed.

Comment: have a look to the selenium api documentation for getAttribute: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String-